# how to remove Anchor and assign anchor in html

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `ul`:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need a thing that I want to make first li  to anchor means

```
<li>1</li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="#">1</li></li>`
```

and remove anchor from 2nd  means

```
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>  to <li>2</li>
```

How can I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple method, that "toggles" the links:

```
$('ul li').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('a').length > 0) {
         $(this).text($(this).text());
    }
    else {
        $(this).html($('<a />').attr('href', '#').text($(this).text()));
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/E2ryt/

**Update:**

From your comment I think you want this:

```
$('ul li').each(function() {
    $(this).html($('<a />').attr('href', '#').text($(this).text()));
}).click(function() {
     $(this).text($(this).text());
});
```

But I'm not 100% sure. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/E2ryt/1/

**Update 2:**

Based on David's comment, you might want this:

```
var lastClicked = null;

$('ul li').click(function() {
    if(lastClicked) {
        lastClicked.html($('<a />').attr('href', '#').text(lastClicked.text()));
    }
    lastClicked = $(this).text($(this).text());
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/E2ryt/2/

Comment: +1. Should be noted however that if there's a jQuery listener for those links, `.live("click", function() { ...` should be used instead of `.click(function() {...` Had my fair share of head-to-desk action because of that :)

Comment: i thing you confused i want to make all li to anchor and on clicked li anchor will be removed.

Comment: @steven: So you want to remove the link if it was clicked? You did not mention this in your question. You just said you want to transform no-links to links and links to no-links. What do you really want? Can you please clarify?

Comment: I don't have the details, but it's starting to look as though mr spielberg wants a menu-like behavior, where only the just-clicked link isn't clickable.